# Karma + Angular1: window.angular.$$csp is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write tests for an Angular 1.6 app using [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) and [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), as well as [`karma-wiredep`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-wiredep) to load the Bower dependencies - at the moment it only contains Angular 1.6.3. When I try to run `karma start` I am able to see the dependencies loading however both Chrome and PhantomJS fail even without loading my application/test code so I assume the problem is with the Karma configuration - the logs do show that angular.js is loading. The errors for both are similar with PhantomJS reporting `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.` however I don't see that happening in the logs. Is there a problem with that way that Karma is configured?

> **Chrome 57.0.2987** (Mac OS X 10.12.3) ERROR
>     Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function
>     at bower_components/angular/angular.js:33345
>
> **PhantomJS 2.1.1** (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
>     TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()')
>     at bower_components/angular/angular.js:33345
>
> **PhantomJS 2.1.1** (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
>     TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.module('ngAnimateMock', ['ng'])
>       .info({ angularVersion: '1.6.3' })')
>     at bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:800

**karma.conf.js**

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['wiredep', 'ng-scenario', 'jasmine'],

    //you can configure wiredep from here (optional) 
    wiredep: {
        dependencies: true,    // default: true  
        devDependencies: true, // default: false  
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    // browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Safari', 'PhantomJS', 'IE'],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "main": "script.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "",
  "authors": [],
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "",
  "ignore": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.6.x"
  }
}
```

**chrome log output**

```
> karma start karma.conf.js
18 03 2017 15:45:22.180:DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
18 03 2017 15:45:22.185:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from /path/to/app/node_modules
18 03 2017 15:45:22.187:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-babel-preprocessor.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.550:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.554:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.555:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.556:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.556:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.586:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-wiredep.
18 03 2017 15:45:22.686:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
18 03 2017 15:45:22.764:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.5.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
18 03 2017 15:45:22.764:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
18 03 2017 15:45:22.779:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
18 03 2017 15:45:22.780:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/84/81q1wl5d5k58flxbpcgqq78w0000gn/T/karma-67345543
18 03 2017 15:45:22.780:DEBUG [launcher]: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --user-data-dir=/var/folders/84/81q1wl5d5k58flxbpcgqq78w0000gn/T/karma-67345543 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-device-discovery-notifications http://localhost:9876/?id=67345543
18 03 2017 15:45:23.538:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
18 03 2017 15:45:23.557:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.751:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket 358rR6cCQQIt8Y11AAAA
18 03 2017 15:45:23.753:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/favicon.ico
18 03 2017 15:45:23.762:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=358rR6cCQQIt8Y11AAAA
18 03 2017 15:45:23.808:INFO [Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.12.3)]: Connected on socket 358rR6cCQQIt8Y11AAAA with id 67345543
18 03 2017 15:45:23.809:DEBUG [launcher]: Chrome (id 67345543) captured in 1.045 secs
18 03 2017 15:45:23.837:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null null
18 03 2017 15:45:23.837:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
18 03 2017 15:45:23.839:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
18 03 2017 15:45:23.856:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.856:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.857:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.859:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.859:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.859:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7a813cc290d592e664331c573a1a796192cdd1ad /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.859:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.860:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js?df746e558e332348ff12e0f08ddae4697abef3cd /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.860:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.861:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.861:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.862:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.872:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?428e663e720ed137f3931dc4e4079d00eb339620 /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.872:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.873:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular/angular.js?367ccb6484896d3b163b691390f735bfca5cf17e /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.873:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.873:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js?88d12e473235d74e75f0db6cbd01396f5aa58e7b /
18 03 2017 15:45:23.874:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.875:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.877:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.890:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:45:23.892:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/context.js
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.12.3) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function
  at bower_components/angular/angular.js:33345


18 03 2017 15:45:24.094:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
18 03 2017 15:45:24.094:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
18 03 2017 15:45:24.452:DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
18 03 2017 15:45:24.452:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/84/81q1wl5d5k58flxbpcgqq78w0000gn/T/karma-67345543
18 03 2017 15:45:24.482:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
```

**phantomjs log output**

```
> karma start
    18 03 2017 15:43:45.349:DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
18 03 2017 15:43:45.354:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from /path/to/app/node_modules
18 03 2017 15:43:45.357:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-babel-preprocessor.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.735:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.739:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.739:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.740:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.741:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.769:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-wiredep.
18 03 2017 15:43:45.880:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
18 03 2017 15:43:45.969:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.5.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
18 03 2017 15:43:45.970:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
18 03 2017 15:43:45.980:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
18 03 2017 15:43:45.981:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/84/81q1wl5d5k58flxbpcgqq78w0000gn/T/karma-75656583
18 03 2017 15:43:45.984:DEBUG [launcher]: /path/to/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /var/folders/84/81q1wl5d5k58flxbpcgqq78w0000gn/T/karma-75656583/capture.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.236:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
18 03 2017 15:43:47.246:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.290:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket qu27-ez-B1uzsqMHAAAA
18 03 2017 15:43:47.295:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=qu27-ez-B1uzsqMHAAAA
18 03 2017 15:43:47.330:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket qu27-ez-B1uzsqMHAAAA with id 75656583
18 03 2017 15:43:47.331:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 75656583) captured in 1.361 secs
18 03 2017 15:43:47.334:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: 

18 03 2017 15:43:47.336:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null null
18 03 2017 15:43:47.336:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
18 03 2017 15:43:47.337:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
18 03 2017 15:43:47.340:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.340:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.341:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.342:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular/angular.js?367ccb6484896d3b163b691390f735bfca5cf17e /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.342:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.342:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7a813cc290d592e664331c573a1a796192cdd1ad /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js?df746e558e332348ff12e0f08ddae4697abef3cd /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js?88d12e473235d74e75f0db6cbd01396f5aa58e7b /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.343:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.344:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.353:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.353:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.353:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.360:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/adapter.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.361:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /path/to/app/node_modules/karma/static/context.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.362:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?428e663e720ed137f3931dc4e4079d00eb339620 /
18 03 2017 15:43:47.362:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /path/to/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.364:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /path/to/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
18 03 2017 15:43:47.440:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

18 03 2017 15:43:47.441:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()')


18 03 2017 15:43:47.441:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]:   http://localhost:9876/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js?367ccb6484896d3b163b691390f735bfca5cf17e:33345 in global code

18 03 2017 15:43:47.443:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.module('ngAnimateMock', ['ng'])
  .info({ angularVersion: '1.6.3' })')

  http://localhost:9876/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?428e663e720ed137f3931dc4e4079d00eb339620:800

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()')
  at bower_components/angular/angular.js:33345


18 03 2017 15:43:47.453:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
18 03 2017 15:43:47.454:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.module('ngAnimateMock', ['ng'])
    .info({ angularVersion: '1.6.3' })')
  at bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:800


18 03 2017 15:43:47.456:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
18 03 2017 15:43:47.456:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
18 03 2017 15:43:47.471:DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code 0
18 03 2017 15:43:47.471:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/84/81q1wl5d5k58flxbpcgqq78w0000gn/T/karma-75656583
18 03 2017 15:43:47.478:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up tracing the issue to to [`karma-ng-scenario`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-scenario) but was not able to resolve it - if I removed it then I was able to load angular without any errors however objects like `browser` were not available in the tests. I noticed in the README they recommend using [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/) for end-to-end testing on new projects, so I ended up implementing it alongside Karma for unit tests.